# How to merge repeated elements in list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of coordinate like:

```
list_coordinate =[(9,0),(9,1),(9,3) ... (53,0),(53,1),(53,3)...(54,0),(54,1)..]

value = []

 for m in range(0,len(list_coordinate)):    
    if m != len(list_coordinate)-1:
        if list_coordinate[m][0]==list_coordinate[m+1][0]:
            value.append(list_coordinate[m][0])`
```

Output of this code:

```
value = [9,9 ,9,...,53,53,53,...,54,54,54,54...]
```

I want to merge this value list for similar element and want output as:

**Expected output:**

```
 [9,53,54]
```

Comment: why not set(value) but it does not give output in the input order

Answer (score 4):

you can use `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
value = [9,9 ,9,53,53,53,54,54,54,54]
g = [k for k,_ in groupby(value)]
print(g)
```

which produces

```
[9, 53, 54]
```

and it is guaranteed to be in the same order as the input list (if it matters).

Basically

```
groupby(iterable[, keyfunc])
```

groups the elements in the iterable, passing to a new group when the key function changes.

If the key function is omitted, the identity function is assumed, and the key for the group will be each element encountered.

So as long as the elements in `value` stay the same, they will be grouped under the same key, which is the element itself.

Note: this works for contiguous repetitions only. In case you wanted to get rid of re-occurring duplicates, you should sort the list first (as groupby [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) explains)

As per your comment below, in case you wanted to operate on the coordinates directly

```
list_coordinate = [(9,0), (9,1), (9,3), (53,0), (53,1), (53,3), (54,0), (54,1)]
g = [k for k,_ in groupby(list_coordinate, lambda x: x[0])]
print(g)
```

produces the same output

```
[9, 53, 54]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pynchia! I did come across the groupby but could not able to figure out how to use it. So can i do the same for the list_coordinate as well without extracting the first elements?

Comment: what output would you like for the `list_coordinate`?

Comment: @Pynchia That groupby in the comments is wrong, the argument to the `keyfunc` would be a single `tuple` , not two elements. You would need either of these for the lambda - `lambda (x,y):x` (Note this only works in Python 2.x)  - or - `lambda x: x[0]` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar absolutely right you are, thank you. Will remove and re-post the comment. I had done it as`'x[0]` initially, then changed it! how wrong

Comment: @user3118718 if `list_coordinate=[(9,0),(9,1),(9,3),(53,0),(53,1),(53,3),(54,0),(54,1)]` then `g=[k for k,_ in groupby(list_coordinate, lambda x: x[0])]` produces the same output `[9, 53, 54]`

Comment: @AnandSKumar why have they deprecated such beautiful syntax in Py3? I think `x[0]` is horrific in comparison

Comment: @Pynchia I am basically trying to find the coordinate lines for detected surfaces in my opencv program. X-coordinate is what i need. SO directly using groupby or what salman suggested is giving me the necessary result. I am going through the groupby documentation. Even list(set(map) gave the result i needed. Thank you!

Comment: Alright, the difference with sets is in the order of the ouput, if it matters. I have described how groupby works because I think the official docs are somewhat dry and could elaborate more.

Comment: So with groupby can i group say 3 elements which are separated by difference of  2? I mean to say if i have the list [2, 67, 4, 69, 92, 66, 109, 68, 98, 59, 60], can I group it into [(2,4), (59,60,66,67,68,69), (92,98,109)]

Comment: you can do it if the values in each group are contiguous and if you can define a function which produces the same key for all the elements in each group. If the condition is not absolute, but relative to previous elements, it can get tricky, if not impossible

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer one-liners, you can do it like this:

```
list(set(map(lambda x: x[0], list_coordinate)))
```

It will output:

```
[9, 53, 54]
```

Note: As set is being used in the code, ordering of the elements is not guaranteed here.

Comment: You should note this does not gurantee any order in the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `OrderedDict` for both of your cases. Firstly for just the `x` coordinates:

```
list_coords = [(9, 0), (9, 1), (9, 3), (53, 0), (53, 1), (53, 3), (54, 0), (54, 1)]
merged = OrderedDict()

for coord in list_coords:
    merged[coord[0]] = 1

print merged.keys()
```

Giving:

```
[9, 53, 54]
```

Note, if for example `(9, 0)` was repeated later on, it would not change the output.

Secondly, for whole coordinates. Note, the data has `(10 ,0)` repeated 3 times:

```
list_coords = [(9, 0), (9, 1), (9, 3), (10, 0), (10, 0), (10, 0), (53, 0), (53, 1), (53, 3), (54, 0), (54, 1)]
merged = OrderedDict()

for coord in list_coords:
    merged[coord] = 1

print merged.keys()
```

Giving:

```
[(9, 0), (9, 1), (9, 3), (10, 0), (53, 0), (53, 1), (53, 3), (54, 0), (54, 1)]
```

Comment: I learnt the use of OrderedDict() with your method. Thanks. Basically the Y-coordinates of the lists are redundant. I want to just group x-coordinate and take average of x-coordinates which are in the specific range.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a set:

```
{ k[0] for k in list_coordinate }
```